# Border for <input type=submit> not working properly in IE7

Tags: css

I want to put border for input type but this is not working properly in IE7

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" style="border : 1px solid #C7D1D4;">
```

In other browser this is working along with IE8 but for IE7 it puts an extra black color border. Can this be resolved or the browser's default activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
    input {
    filter:chroma(color=#000000);
    border : 1px solid #C7D1D4;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```